# Lipschitz manifold and semi-algebraic is Lipschitz graph?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, singularity-theory

It is known that there are Lipschitz manifolds that are not Lipschitz graphs and $C^1$ manifold is locally $C^1$ graph.

If $M\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is a Lipschitz manifold (with the outer distance) and algebraic, then M is locally Lipschitz graph?

Comment: What is a Lipschitz manifold? What is a Lipschitz graph? Are you thinking about subspaces of $R^n$?

Comment: @studiosus, Edit:
Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ a topological manifold of dimension $n$. $M$ is called a Lipschitz Manifold if for each $x\in M$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a map bi-Lipschitz $\varphi: U \to B$ (i.e., exists constants $K,k>0$ such that $k\|x-y\|\leq \|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\|\leq K\|x-y\|, \,\,\, \forall x,y\in U$), where $B$ is an open  of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $U$ is an open  of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$. $Graph(f)$ is called a  Lipschitz graph if it is a Lipschitz manifold or equivalently if $f$ is Lipschitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the extra explanation, there is a simple counter example: round circle in the plane. I suspect though, that you actually meant to ask something else.

Edit: Here is a local example. Take a polygonal *unknot* $K$ in $R^3$ such that the projection of $K$ to any affine plane in $R^2$ is not 1-1. Let $M\subset R^4$ denote the cone over $M$ from a point $p\in R^4\setminus R^3$. Then $M$ is semialgebraic, Lipschitz manifold (the latter is since $K$ is a polygonal unknot). However, at the point $p$, $M$ is not the graph of any function of two variables with values in $R^2$ (for any choice of an affine plane in $R^4$).

**Edit 2.** Here are some further details.

Let $K$ be a nontrivial polygonal knot in $R^3$. Then (affine) projection of $K$ to every plane in $R^3$ has at least 2 crossings (actually, at least 3, but we need just 2). By subdividing edges of $K$ further, we can assume that none of the edges of $K$ appears in both of these crossings.

Now, remove an edge from $K$. The result is a finite polygonal chain $C$ which has the property that projection $\pi(C)$ of $C$ to every plane in $R^3$ has at least one crossing, i.e. the restriction $\pi|C$ is not injective.

Lemma. If $C$ is a finite polygonal chain in $R^3$, then there exists a polygonal $T\subset R^3$ unknot containing $C$ as a subset.

Proof. Take a piecewise-linear homeomorphism $f: R^3\to R^3$ which maps $C$ to a straight line segment $c$. Next, let $t\subset R^3$ be a triangle containing $c$ as an edge. Lastly, set $T=f^{-1}(t)$. qed

In the case of the chain $C$ that we constructed above, the unknot $T$ has the property that its projection to every plane in $R^3$ is non-injective. Next, embed $R^3$ in $R^4$ as the hyperplane $x_4=0$. Set $p=(0,0,0,1)\in R^4$ and let $M\subset R^4$ be the cone with the tip $p$ and the base $T$. In other words, $M$ is the union of 2-dimensional triangles $S_i$ such that $p$ is a vertex of each $S_i$ and the opposite edge of $S_i$ is an edge $e_i$ of $T$. In particular, $M$ is a 2-dimensional piecewise-linear manifold with boundary (its boundary is the unknot $T$). If you really do not like this boundary, just remove it. By construction, $M$ is (real) semi-algebraic as a finite union of semialgebraic subsets $S_i$. Since $T$ is an unknot, there exists a piecewise-linear homeomorphism of $R^3$ sending $T$ to a triangle. Coning-off this homeomorphism from $p$, we obtain a PL homeomorphism of $R^4$ sending $M$ to a convex surface $M'$ (cone over a triangle). This PL homeomorphism is clearly bilipschitz. Composing with a further PL homeomorphism of $R^4$ we flaten $M'$ to a 2-dimensional triangle.

Lastly:

Lemma. The surface $M$, locally, at $p$, is not a graph of any function.

Proof. Suppose it is a graph of a function $R^2\to R^2$. Hence, exist an affine projection $\pi: R^4\to R^2$ which is injective on $U\cap M$, where $M$ is a small neighborhood of $p$ in $R^4$. Let $H\subset R^4$ be a hyperplane given by equation $x_4=r$, where $r<1$ is sufficiently close to $1$ so that
$$
L=H\cap M\subset U 
$$
Then $\pi|H: H\to R^2$ is injective on $L$. However, with identification of $H$ with $R^3$, the unknot $L$ is just a scaled-down copy of the unknot $T$. This means that there exists an affine  projection $R^3\to R^2$ whose restriction to $T$ is 1-1. Contradiction.

Comment: There are counter examples to the local problem too. Please, edit your question instead if making comments in various places. Then I will write a proper answer.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio: See my edit and let me know if it answers the question you meant to ask. Note that I took definition of an $n$-dimensional Lipschitz submanifold $M\subset R^m$ to be stricter than yours: For every $x\in M$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $R^m$ and a bilipschitz homeomorphism which sends $U$ to $U'\subset R^m$ and sends $U\cap M$ to an open subset of $R^n\subset R^m$. Even with this stricter definition, you get a counter example.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio: Every finite union of semialgebraic sets is semialgebraic. Every Euclidean simplex is obviously semialgebraic.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio:  If you mean real-algebraic, then I am pretty sure I can make an example in $R^4$. Complex-algebraic - would require much more work but is probably possible once dimension is high enough. I will give more details on constructing unknots in $R^3$ when I have more time. An easy physical example is the following: Take a long unknotted piece of rope whose ends are glued together. Then, without cutting the rope, tie any knot you like on it. This is an unknot in the mathematical sense, but its projection to every plane is not 1-1.

Comment: @EdsonSampaio: I did not claim that there exists such an unknot. What I am saying that there exists a PL surface in $R^4$ with this property. See Edit 2 with details.